# jQuery: trigger click or focus input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a page with multiple divs that all look like the example below. 
Each div contains a field, a hidden field and a button.

How can I achieve that by click on the button the (visible) input field gets triggered ? 
I need to trigger either a click or focus as both fire the same function.

Each button in question has the `class="triggerBtn"` and the corresponding input field has the `class="inputField"`.

**Example div:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inputField" id="field1" name="field1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary triggerBtn">Find</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".triggerBtn").click(function(e){ myFunction(); });` and `$(".inputField").focus(function(e){ myFunction(); });`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
$(".triggerBtn").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.inputField').focus();
});
```

Comment: You guess... Like all of us. As long as this question is unclear, we can't help him/her.

Comment: You guessed right ! :) Thanks for the quick reply and sorry I wasnt clear enough.

Answer (score 6):

add 
    Onclick="function()" [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
if you need to trigger it manually using jquery you can to this by

```
$("#field1").trigger("click");
```

[see also here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".triggerBtn").on("click",function(e){
      $(this).closest("div").find(".inputField").click();
     //or $(this).closest("div").find(".inputField").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".triggerBtn").parent().children("input[type:text]").first().focus()
```

Comment: shouldn't `input[type:text]` be `input[type='text']`?

Answer (score -1):

Updated Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmL4y/3/

```
$(document).on("click",".triggerBtn", function() { 
    var inputField =  $(this).closest('div').find('.inputField');
    if($(inputField).is(":visible"))
    {
       $(inputField ).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: How can you focus an array of elements ?